# Facing NotImplementedError in pytorch model training on google colab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pytorch

I want to make project that have 20 class in google Collaboratory. In this project, I want to make a classification image using CNN algorithm. After I was run the training it show the following error.

```
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-59-0a2f6a1d50aa> in <module>()
     14 
     15         optimizer.zero_grad()
---> 16         outputs=model(images)
     17         loss=loss_function(outputs,labels)
     18         loss.backward()

1 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _forward_unimplemented(self, *input)
    199         registered hooks while the latter silently ignores them.
    200     """
--> 201     raise NotImplementedError
    202 
    203 

NotImplementedError:
```

Here I attach code of my model and train

Model

```
class CNN(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self,num_classes=25):
    super(CNN,self).__init__()
    self.conv1=nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3,out_channels=12,kernel_size=3,stride=1,padding=1)
        #Shape= (256,12,150,150)
    self.bn1=nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=12)
        #Shape= (256,12,150,150)
    self.relu1=nn.ReLU()
        #Shape= (256,12,150,150)
        
    self.pool=nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
        #Reduce the image size be factor 2
        #Shape= (256,12,75,75)
        
        
    self.conv2=nn.Conv2d(in_channels=12,out_channels=20,kernel_size=3,stride=1,padding=1)
        #Shape= (256,20,75,75)
    self.relu2=nn.ReLU()
        #Shape= (256,20,75,75)
        
        
        
    self.conv3=nn.Conv2d(in_channels=20,out_channels=32,kernel_size=3,stride=1,padding=1)
        #Shape= (256,32,75,75)
    self.bn3=nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=32)
        #Shape= (256,32,75,75)
    self.relu3=nn.ReLU()
        #Shape= (256,32,75,75)
        
        
    self.fc=nn.Linear(in_features=75 * 75 * 32,out_features=num_classes)
        
        
        
        #Feed forwad function
        
    def forward(self,input):
        output=self.conv1(input)
        output=self.bn1(output)
        output=self.relu1(output)
            
        output=self.pool(output)
            
        output=self.conv2(output)
        output=self.relu2(output)
            
        output=self.conv3(output)
        output=self.bn3(output)
        output=self.relu3(output)
            
            
            #Above output will be in matrix form, with shape (256,32,75,75)
            
        output=output.view(-1,32*75*75)
            
            
        output=self.fc(output)
            
        return output
```

Train

```
best_accuracy=0.0

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    
    #Evaluation and training on training dataset
    model.train()
    train_accuracy=0.0
    train_loss=0.0
    
    for i, (images,labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            images=Variable(images.cuda())
            labels=Variable(labels.cuda())
            
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs=model(images)
        loss=loss_function(outputs,labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        
        train_loss+= loss.cpu().data*images.size(0)
        _,prediction=torch.max(outputs.data,1)
        
        train_accuracy+=int(torch.sum(prediction==labels.data))
        
    train_accuracy=train_accuracy/train_count
    train_loss=train_loss/train_count
    
    
    # Evaluation on testing dataset
    model.eval()
    
    test_accuracy=0.0
    for i, (images,labels) in enumerate(test_loader):
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            images=Variable(images.cuda())
            labels=Variable(labels.cuda())
            
        outputs=model(images)
        _,prediction=torch.max(outputs.data,1)
        test_accuracy+=int(torch.sum(prediction==labels.data))
    
    test_accuracy=test_accuracy/test_count
    
    
    print('Epoch: '+str(epoch)+' Train Loss: '+str(train_loss)+' Train Accuracy: '+str(train_accuracy)+' Test Accuracy: '+str(test_accuracy))
    
    #Save the best model
    if test_accuracy>best_accuracy:
        torch.save(model.state_dict(),'best_checkpoint.model')
        best_accuracy=test_accuracy
```

**There is a red line in the code outputs=model(images) when I run the train**

Comment: why does your forward function has  `*` in `forward(self,*input)`?

Comment: I have edit it from my google colab. It seems getting same error. I think its my nn.Module was wrong but I don't know in where